# Excel Macros in Sharepoint

Tags: excel-macro

I'm new to SharePoint, so even though I saw many posts on this subject, I didn't see any answer that seemed to actually apply necessarily to my question.

So, our company has an excel workbook that is accessible by all, though only editable by some. There are two options to open this workbook: "in browser" or "in app"
I've read the official post about macros being disabled in one format versus the other (and then one post that said just outright that you can't use macros with Excel from SharePoint). My question is, what is true?
The situation is that with the way our excel file is, people have to go into the options of the search function and change the search parameters every time they get into the workbook in the app version to look in values instead of the default; formulas. We'd like to have an auto run macro that alleviates this for all users, but this sounds potentially impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Macros can only be run by the desktop Excel client. They cannot be run by Office Online or mobile applications.

Comment: Thank you. Part of my confusion was that whenever we open "in app" it just appears to be launching our desktop Excel program anyway, so I wasn't sure there was an actual difference.